Can I use Multinomial Logistic Regression's probabilities as proxies for proportions?
Summary of the Problem:
I am exploring methods to simultaneously predict the proportions of different tree species within 250 square meter forest plots using ALS (Airborne Laser Scanning) and spectral data (continuous variables). While multinomial logistic regression is typically for categorical outcomes, I found that the probabilities provided by them (e.g., Spruce 60%, Pine 30%, Birch 10%) match closely the actual proportions obsevred in field. For instance, the model might predict the probabilities of Spruce, Pine, and Birch in a plot as 60%, 30%, and 10%, respectively, which I then use as proxies for species proportions.
I use the function multinom() from the R package nnet.
What I’ve Tried:
In addition to multinomial logistic regression, I have experimented with Dirichlet regression, random forests, nearest neighbors, neural networks, and XGBoost. Surprisingly, the multinomial logistic regression has outperformed these methods in terms of precision. This has led me to further investigate why this method might be more effective in this context.
My Doubts:
Is it statistically valid to use multinomial logistic regression for predicting continuous proportions, considering that its primary application is for categorical outcomes?
Can the probabilities output by this model be accurately interpreted as species proportions within each plot?
Why might multinomial logistic regression perform better in predicting these proportions compared to other models I have tried?
Seeking Suggestions:
I would greatly appreciate insights into the appropriateness of using multinomial logistic regression in this way and any theories or experiences that could explain its unexpected effectiveness. Additionally, recommendations for alternative approaches or adjustments to current methodologies that might enhance accuracy or provide better insights would be extremely helpful.

Maybe Dirichlet regression could be helpful here.
